# oracle - max with case

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select case when cntrctr_lcns_seq_no is null
                                   then 1
                                   else max(cntrctr_lcns_seq_no)
                                   end as cntrctr_lcns_seq_no
                                   from nuwmsweb.cntrctr_lcns_info
                                    where third_party_id = thirdPartyId
                                    group by third_party_id
```

I think you an see what i'm trying to do. Get the max seq_no for a specific id. But I get the error "not a single group group clause".

This select statement is part of a larger insert.

Thanks!

update: this is the whole statement

```
insert into nuwmsweb.CNTRCTR_LCNS_INFO
    (third_party_id,cntrctr_lcns_seq_no,cntrctr_lcns_no,
    lcns_st_cd,certfn_level_type_cd,cntrctr_type_cd,cut_tap_authy_ind,
    stat_type_nm)
    VALUES(thirdPartyId,(select max(case when cntrctr_lcns_seq_no is null
                                   then 1
                                   else cntrctr_lcns_seq_no
                                   end) as cntrctr_lcns_seq_no
                                   from nuwmsweb.cntrctr_lcns_info
                                    where third_party_id = thirdPartyId
                                    group by third_party_id
                                    ),
          licenseNumber,licenseState,licenseLevel,licenseType,cutTap,status);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max aggregate function will ignore null values, so you don't need the case statement or the group by as you want the max over the entire returned set.

```
select
    coalesce(max(cntrctr_lcns_seq_no), 1) as cntrctr_lcns_seq_no
from nuwmsweb.cntrctr_lcns_info
where third_party_id = thirdPartyId
```

Comment: not quite, i actually want 1 returned if there is not yet an id in the table.

Comment: not sure what coalsce does... but it works if I do `select     coalesce(max(cntrctr_lcns_seq_no) + 1, 1) as cntrctr_lcns_seq_no from nuwmsweb.cntrctr_lcns_info where third_party_id = thirdPartyId` note the `+ 1`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select coalesce (max(cntrctr_lcns_seq_no),1) as cntrctr_lcns_seq_no
  from nuwmsweb.cntrctr_lcns_info
 where third_party_id = thirdPartyId
```

(or you can use Oracle's `nvl` instead of ANSI's `coalesce` if you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select  max(case when cntrctr_lcns_seq_no is null then 1
        else cntrctr_lcns_seq_no end) as cntrctr_lcns_seq_no
from nuwmsweb.cntrctr_lcns_info
where third_party_id = thirdPartyId                                     
group by third_party_id
```

Comment: i tried that but i get a cannot insert into error. Another words, this is returning null rater than 1 when that id is not yet in the table

Comment: @kralco626: what do you mean with you are gettinh a "cannot insert into error"?, there is no `INSERT` in the statement. What is the rest of the query you are executing?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :**

The error you are getting is because you are not including the third_party_id in the group by clause.

Try...

```
select max(case when cntrctr_lcns_seq_no is null
                                   then 1
                                   else cntrctr_lcns_seq_no
                                   end) as cntrctr_lcns_seq_no
                                   from nuwmsweb.cntrctr_lcns_info
                                    where third_party_id = thirdPartyId
                                    group by third_party_id
```

If you really want to use this syntax for a different (more complicated query). Also, you should add the third_party_id in the group by clause.

But max already ignores nulls, so wouldn't a query like this be more descriptive of what you are trying to do?

```
select third_party_id, max(nvl(cntrctr_lcns_seq_no,1))
        from nuwmsweb.cntrctr_lcns_info
        where third_party_id = thirdPartyId
        group by third_party_id
```

Comment: ya i like that. i must be doing something else wrong because i keep getting a cannot insert null error